# Creating Reactive Kafka SenderRecord from Flux<DataBuffer>

Tags: spring-cloud, kafka-producer-api, spring-cloud-gateway, reactive-kafka

I am doing a prototype integrating Spring Cloud Gateway with Reactive Kafka. My goal is to push the post body to kafka. I have access to *Flux* which could potentially give me the body in chunks. Need expert advice how to convert this Flux of DataBuffer to a SenderRecord and push this to kafka nonblocking.

I tried with ***DataBufferUtils.join*** to merge the DataBuffer to get the bytes[] and uses this create a SenderRecord. Is there a better way to this (can we avoid allocating the bytes array)?

Implementation detail: I have Spring Cloud Gateway Global Filter for kafka (url structure: `kafka://<producer-template>?topic=<topicname>`. Then read the body ie flux and create kafkaSender.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not familiar at all with the kafka apis. Do they have an API to stream data? If not, data will need to read into memory.

Comment: @spencergibb thanks. I am referring to following example from reactive-kafka documentation https://projectreactor.io/docs/kafka/release/reference/#api-guide-sender . KafkaSender uses a flux of SenderRecord to send data to kafka. While in Spring Cloud Gateway  global filter we have Flux<DataBuffer> . So I guess only option available now would be to join all DataBuffer and convert to bytes and then create a SenderRecord.